# Cannot create custom themes for salesforce

Tags: css, home-page-component

We are trying to create a custom salesforce theme following these instructions:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdNJwzhok_M

> 1. Navigate to Setup | Personal Setup | App Setup | Customize | User Interface Settings, and check 'Show Custom Sidebar Components on all
>      Pages' is checked.
> 2. Navigate to Setup | Personal Setup | App Setup | Customize | Home | Hompe Page Components, and: a. Click on the 'New' Button under
>      Componenets. b. Give it a simple name, like 'Matrix Theme' and change
>      its type to HTM Area. c. Click Next. Choose Narrow (Left) Column. and
>      check the Show HTML. d. Paste the following and Save: "less than sign"
>      style "greater than sign" * { background-color:black !important;
>      background-image:none!important; color:green!important; font-style:
>      bold!important; border:none !important; } "less than
>      sign"/style"greater than sign"
> 3. Make sure the Home Page Layput Section has the Dark Theme (the new componenent) displayed in your ptofile(s) you wanted.

However, they do not appear to work. My css code is the same as in the video:

```
<style>
*{
background-color:black !important;
background-image:none !important;
color:white !important;
border:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Is it possible that this functionality was removed in later versions of Salesforce? I am sure I followed the instructions correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "theming" relies on an old hack that would allow you to insert arbitrary HTML, CSS and JavaScript into the page in a home page component. It hasn't been available for new components since Summer '14, when the HTML editor was replaced with a rich text editor that only allows white listed tags.

You can change the logo for your app through the Apps page in Setup, but any custom theming requires replacing standard pages with Visualforce or (eventually) Lightning.